# 2D Matrix Multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I want to write a function which allows us to do multiplication of 2 2D matrices. This function has the following parameters as inputs: list1 and list2 are 2D arrays. They are transferred to the function as pointers. Row1, col1, row2, col2 are int values for the size of list1 and list2.

When I have square matrices for the inputs I get correct results. For example; list1[2][2] = {1,2,3,4} and list2[2][2] = {1,2,3,4} gives the result {7,10,15,22}.

When I don't use square matrices I don't get correct results. For example; list1[2][1] = {1,2} and list2[1][2] = {1,2} gives the result {1,4,4,0} which is wrong and list1[2][1] = {1,2} and list2[1][2] = {1,2} gives a garbage value instead of a scalar number.

EDIT : Fixed the returning pointer problem but I still don't get the correct result

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray2D(int* list, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            cout << list[i * col + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
}

int* matrixMultiplication(int* list1, int* list2, int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) {
    if (col1 != row2) {
        cout << "Array sizes don't match";
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        int* newList = new int[5];
        newList[0] = 0;
        newList[1] = 0;
        newList[2] = 0;
        newList[3] = 0;
        newList[4] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < col1; k++) {
                    newList[i * col1 + j] = newList[i * col1 + j] + list1[i * col1 + k] * list2[k * col1 + j];
                }
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int list1[2][1] = {1,2};

    int list2[1][2] = {1,2};
    

    int row1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    
    int col1 = sizeof(list1[0]) / sizeof(list1[0][0]);

    int row2 = sizeof(list2) / sizeof(list2[0]);

    int col2 = sizeof(list2[0]) / sizeof(list2[0][0]);
   

    int* result = matrixMultiplication((int*)list1, (int*)list2, row1, col1, row2, col2);

    printArray2D((int*)result, row1, col2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You return the pointer to the local variable destroyed after the return statement. The compiler should warn you about this issue and you should not ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: I changed the returned value from newList to result, now it is different from the local variable in the function

Comment: You seem to have to invest in any good C++ book. You did not change the returned value, you renamed the destination variable name.

Comment: Fixed the returning pointer problem but I still don't get the correct result

Comment: The only C++ feature I see in your code is std::cout. The rest is (poorly written) C. It seems to me that you are trying to tackle a problem that is way over your understanding of the language. I have two suggestions (not mutually exclusive) 1. get a nice book and start from easier exercises 2. find some implementation online and try to learn few language features that.

Comment: shouldn't this `list2[k * col1 + j]` be `list2[k * col2 + j]` instead?

Comment: and also, this `newList[i * col1 + j] = newList[i * col1 + j]` shouldn't be `newList[i * col2 + j] = newList[i * col2 + j]`  ?

Comment: *"which is wrong"* -- you neglected to mention what would be correct. (Good bug reporting -- and requests for debugging help -- should include both the actual *and expected* results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mix in one function two entirely different matters, a memory allocation and a matrix-matrix multiplication!

I would do `C = A * B` like this:

```
bool matrixMultiplication(int* C, int* A, int * B, int rowA, int colA, int rowB, int colB) {

    if (colA != rowB) return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < colB; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < colA; k++)
                C[i*colB + j] += A[i*colA + k] * B[k*colB + j];

    return false;
}
```

so, in the main script have something like this:

```
bool error = matrixMultiplication( /* parameters */ );
if ( error ) {
    std::cout << "invalid matrix dimensions" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is generally a VERY BAD idea to hide memory allocations under routines in this way! Design the code better by separation of concerns. The scope of the routine is to multiply two matrices `A` and `B`, and store results to `C`.

**Note:**

1. Make sure that all values under `C` are set to zero, in advance!
2. We have a disagreement in our choices about this line: `C[i*colB + j] += A[i*colA + k] * B[k*colB + j];`